# How to create a drawer with list view in QML?

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qtquickcontrols2

I have created a drawer, which will appear after click and drag from top of the screen using mouse.I have also added a list view. But the problem is; when more list items are added in the list view, drawer height is not correct. Extra added list items are visible in the top of the screen even without dragging the drawer down. Is there any solution for this?

Comment: If you only want to prevent the items to exceed your drawer's size, set the property `clip: true` of the drawer. But you won't be able to see the hidden items. Maybe you should use a `ScrollView` whose size would fit the drawer's size.

Comment: Listview is already having scrolling property. Then what is the use of using it ?

Comment: Yeah, my mistake. So maybe just set `clip: true` into the ListView [see the documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-modelviewsdata-modelview.html)

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Comment: Thanks @user@2436719.it works.

Comment: @Mitch, I was having a drawer height issue when using a list view inside of it. Issue was, some the list view items are seems to be appeared in the screen even before dragging down the drawer. It could fixed by setting the clip property to true.

Comment: You should also set the `ListView`'s `visible:false` when the drawer is up, to increase performance. Otherwise it will continuosly calculate the clipping.